# Laravel 5.8.x (with AdminLTE) not showing flash messages

Tags: php, laravel, flash-message

I noticed that my flash messages for some reason stopped showing.

Using the password reset route (/passwords/reset), I saw that the e-mail is being sent, however, the return after POST should display a message, something like "E-mail sent".

The point is that the message is not displayed, either in cases of failure or success.

**resources/views/passwords/email.blade.php**

```
@if (session('status'))
     <div class="alert alert-success">
          {{ session('status') }}
     </div>
@endif
```

**vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/SendsPasswordResetEmails.php**

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateEmail($request);

    $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
        $this->credentials($request)
    );

    return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($request, $response)
                : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
}

...

protected function sendResetLinkResponse(Request $request, $response)
{
    return back()->with('status', trans($response));
}
```

**EDIT 1 (2020-02-24)**: Can middleware interfere in this case?

Here is my **app/Http/Kernel.php**

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
];

protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
];
```

Could someone help me display flash messages again?

Thanks!

Comment: dump `$response` and see if the value is passed

Comment: `$response` is OK. The value is `passwords.sent`

Comment: This `$response` should appear in my view, but for some reason Laravel is ignoring (or not saving) the flash messages

Answer (score 0):

In Your Controller

```
session()->flash('status', "Send Successfully");
return  redirect()->back();
```

In Your View

```
@if (session()->has('status'))
<div class="alert alert-success">{{ session()->get('status') }}</div>
@endif
```

Comment: Didn't work.

I put `dd(session())` and the **_flash** attribute looks like this:

`"_flash" => array:2 [▼
          "old" => []
          "new" => []
]`